# Searching the same word with different cases

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query where I need to search the same word which has different cases, both upper and smaller case letters.

For this, I have written a query like this,

```sql
SELECT <Name_field> FROM <Table_Name>
WHERE <Name_field> LIKE '%ABC%' OR <Name_field> LIKE '%abc%'
```

This query worked for me.

In order to include more searches without OR, how can I write the condition?

That single condition should fetch both 'ABC' and 'abc'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```sql
 WHERE LOWER(< Name_field >) LIKE '%abc%'
```

or

```sql
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(< Name_field >,'abc','i') --where "i" means case "i"nsensitive search
```

Answer (score 1):

On oracle 12.2+ you can use Statement-Level collation: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLLATE-Operator.html

```sql
SELECT <Name_field> FROM <Table_Name>
WHERE <Name_field> collate binary_ci LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do:

```
SELECT <Name_field> FROM <Table_Name>
WHERE lower(<Name_field>) LIKE '%abc%'
```

Comment: Yes! This is correct.